# How to run a hyperlink in Google sheets with App scripts

Tags: hyperlink

Create script to run a hyperlink "Go to last entry" from Range "A2".

New to scripting and I want script in Google sheets to run a hyperlink from a cell.

I have already created a taskbar dropdown menu with the name of the hyperlink but dont know how to write the script to run the hyperlink that is for example in Range A2.

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `rum a hyperlink`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Apologies (auto correct spelling function). I have created a hyperlink that is for example in range A1. I want to know how this hyperlink can be run (code) with Google apps script. I have already created a menu drop down to activate the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Apologies (auto correct spelling function). I have created a hyperlink that is for example in range A1. I want to know how this hyperlink can be run (code) with Google apps script. I have already created a menu drop down to activate the script.`, I couldn't still understand `this hyperlink can be run (code) with Google apps script`. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Answer (score 0):

This script will run the hyperlink in cell A2 when clicked (this script assumes that the hyperlink is a formula that can be extracted from the cell using `getFormula()`.):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getA1Notation() === 'A2' && e.value === 'Go to last row') {
    var hyperlink = sheet.getRange('A2').getFormula(); // Get the hyperlink formula from cell A2
    var url = extractUrlFromHyperlink(hyperlink);

    if (url !== null) {
      openUrl(url);
    }
  }
}

// Extracts the URL from a hyperlink formula
function extractUrlFromHyperlink(hyperlink) {
  var match = /"(.*?)"/.exec(hyperlink);
  return match ? match[1] : null;
}

// Opens a URL in a new tab
function openUrl(url) {
  var html = '<script>window.open("' + url + '");</script>';
  HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
    .setWidth(10)
    .setHeight(10)
    .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still encounter difficulty "Error message". I have entered the script as below; function GoToLastEntry(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Week Focus MS');
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getA1Notation() === 'A2' && e.value === 'Go to last entry') {
    var hyperlink = sheet.getRange('A2').getFormula(); // Get the hyperlink formula from cell A2
    var url = extractUrlFromHyperlink(hyperlink);
    if (url !== null) {
      openUrl(url);
    }
  }
};  Error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading source)

Comment: The error message you're encountering suggests that the e (event) object might be undefined, which typically happens when the function is not triggered by a relevant event (such as an edit in the spreadsheet). you can modify the script to use a different trigger, such as an onOpen trigger. hope its helpful